# How can I get the purchase data after an order, in WooCommerce and send it as a POST request?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to send the details of an order (when the order is placed) via an HTTP POST request (details susch as firstname, lastname, order name etc.).

The data should be send to my Node/Express backend, and should be as JSON.

Here's my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'send_order_data' );

function send_order_data( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $url = 'http://exemple.com/custom-url';

    if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {

        //Get the order and customer data
        //Send the data as a HTTP POST request && the data should be as JSON

        exit;
    }
```

Node/Express backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// @route   POST '/api'
// @desc    
// @access  Public
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // Get data from WC post request
  console.log('new WC request');
  console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );


    if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) { 

            $url = "https://www.test.com";

            $response = wp_remote_post(
                $url,
                array(
                    'body' => array(
                        'firstname' => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
                        'lastname' =>  $order->get_billing_address_2(),
                    )
                )
            );
    }
});
```

For more details - check [Get order details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827027/1117368)